# Show lines filtered by different values from the same column

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-athena

I have a system in which in a column, we register if it is a bill, a sales order, an invoice, a purchase order etc. This means that for the same ID we can have more than 1 transaction (for example, ID1 could have 1 lines of revenues and 2 lines of costs):

```
ID  TYPE       AMOUNT
 1  Bill         5 
 1  Bill         2 
 1  PurcOder     2 
 2  SAlesOrder   1
```

etc

I'd like to extract all, showing 1 line per type of each ID, with the sum for each type category, how could I do it?

Thank you

Comment: Can you please show the desired output?

Comment: Please Edit your question to include the desired output for the sample data you have shown.

Answer (score 0):

`SELECT SUM(AMOUNT) from table_name GROUP BY ID, TYPE`